# SettingWithCopyWarning: in python

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

[image]HOW TO DEAL WITH THIS WARNING?

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Test_Values':y_test.values,'Predicted_Values':y_pred,'Correct_Values':False,"Wrong_Values":False})
df2.head()

for i in df2.index:
    if df2['Test_Values'][i]==df2['Predicted_Values'][i]:
        df2['Correct_Values'][i]=True
    else:
        df2['Wrong_Values'][i]=True
```

Iris Flower Classification:

Iris flower has three species; setosa, versicolor, and virginica, which differs according to their measurements. Now assume that you have the measurements of the iris flowers according to their species, and here your task is to train a machine learning model that can learn from the measurements of the iris species and classify them.

Although the Scikit-learn library provides a dataset for iris flower classification, you can also download the same dataset from here for the task of iris flower classification with Machine Learning.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using loops:

```
import numpy as np
df2['Correct_Values'] = np.where(df2['Test_Values']==df2['Predicted_Values'], True, df2['Correct_Values'])
df2['Wrong_Values'] = np.where(df2['Test_Values']!=df2['Predicted_Values'], True, df2['Wrong_Values'])
```

Alternatively, if you still want to use a loop you should use .loc:

```
for i in df2.index:
    if df2.loc[i, 'Test_Values']==df2.loc[i, 'Predicted_Values']:
        df2.loc[i, 'Correct_Values']=True
    else:
        df2.loc[i, 'Wrong_Values']=True
```